# APC uptime 0 because of Fast

Tags: fastcgi, alternative-php-cache

I have a VPS using Parallels/Plesk (11.0.9 Update #22, last updated at Oct 31, 2012 03:33 AM
CentOS 6.3 (Final) x86_64)

I have apache (CGI/FastCGI) installed and nginx as reverse proxy. Everything is working just fine. I installed APC for caching, but the issue is that the uptime is 0 always. It's restarting each 15 seconds or so. I checked everywhere and can't find a solution to fix it.

The server have the grace restart enabled, but every 6 hours, which shouldn't influence the APC uptime. 
Searching in Google I found that this could be related to Apache, running with FCGId instead of FastCGI. Plesk/Apache is using this config file: usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/service/php_over_fastcgi.php which content is:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
<Files ~ (\.php)>
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    FCGIWrapper <?php echo $VAR->server->webserver->apache->phpCgiBin ?> .p$
    Options +ExecCGI
    allow from all
</Files>
```

Is here the issue or elsewhere ? How can I fix this to work with FastCGI and make APC working properly. 
I forgot to specify that even if the uptime is below one minute, APC is doing pretty good job caching (92% are hits).

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem and I'd like to know whether the starter solved this or not. Hope he did it and can help me here! Thanks, Twain

Comment: @Twain At this moment there is no solution, other than "upgrading" to Cpanel, where the support is much better. I started two threads on Parallels forum and after that I insisted to get this issue fixed, they banned my account. When I tweeted that the support is horrible they contacted me and looks like they answered here: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?p=652065. However, they answer it is not helping us, but I made another account and I started replying them in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP will die and then a fresh one will be spawned when PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS is hit. You can tune this figure with:

```
DefaultInitEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 5000
```

Comment: No.. Is not this the issue.  I posted in my question,  as comment,  a link to the thread on the Plesk forum where we are discussing this issue.  Apparently,  even if the fastcgi is chosen in Plesk,  the server is working with fcgid (fastcgi is not completely implemented).  Acest is not working in fcgid.  Looks like even the developers have no idea how to fix this issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to Fcgi terminating application. Depending of your load (number of requests per hour) It can be either 
http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestsperprocess

or http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgididletimeout (i think this suits better)

Try increasing this values to achieve effect.

Comment: No,  is not this the issue.  Read my comments I posted on Aaron answer.